# Faster multitrack mixdowns in Adobe Audition CC

Tags: adobe-audition, time, speed, export, mixdown

A 1-hour multitrack session takes more than six hours to export as a multitrack mixdown. I suspect pitch shifts and effects play a role.

How can I speed up my multitrack mixdowns and is there a way to capture audio output live for draft review?

Version: 2015.2.1 Release. Build: 9.2.1.19

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I see you've already found a work-around, but to get a real answer we would need more information. Your computer specs would be very helpful and details about the track-count and processing used (such as you put in your answer) would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Each clip was in its own track in Audition. Consolidating the 15+ clips into 3 or 4 tracks (as they overlap) and moving track-level Pitch Shift effects to clip-level effects took my mixdown time down from 6 hours to 30 minutes.